# Cannot find locci, lclnths, lboost_regex while compiling

Tags: c++, eclipse, occi

This is the result of the compilation:

```
-lrt -lssl -locci -lclntsh -lboost_regex -lboost_thread -llog4cpp -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -locci
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [GameServer2010] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the file `libocci.so` is on your machine? You need to indicate the linker the lib location with `-L` (and do the same for the other libraries)